# sending a transaction requires a signer

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ganache, ether

I have an NFT Contract and I need to mint NFTs. Also I have a second contract
for handling buying and selling NFTs into this contract.

I am using the ethers library.

this is my code for config:

```
static async Initial(): Promise<any> {

    let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(config.contractConfig.url);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    
    this.tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(config.contractConfig.nftAddress, NFT.abi, provider);
    this.dNFT = new ethers.Contract(config.contractConfig.dortajNftAddress, DNFT.abi, signer);

}
```

config address:

```
  export default {
     nftAddress: '0x444F15B115ED9663DAE46786a34AA3F6E8c0B57D',
     dortajNftAddress: '0x8e4bE2a3BD1169596c38952D8e837b20D419Bcd1',
     url : 'HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'
   }
```

now i need to use this function for mint nft :

```
        let transaction = await this.tokenContract.mintToken();
        const tx = await transaction.wait();
```

but it show me this error:

> Error: sending a transaction requires a signer (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.5.0)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
this.tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(config.contractConfig.nftAddress, NFT.abi, provider);
```

try to pass `signer` instead of `provider`.

Comment: could you explain why show me this error ?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70914004/uncaught-in-promise-error-sending-a-transaction-requires-a-signer)

Comment: changing from provider to signer worked for me.